# Create subzones in firewallD

Tags: centos, iptables, firewalld

In firewalld, I can assign a zone to an network interface. A zone contains some firewall rules.

Now I have a network interface with different levels of trust (`172.16.1.1/32` should have special access in the `172.16.1.0/24` network). For example SSH access for an admin host.

The only way I found to realize that, is to use a rich rule. But I am not happy with this approach, because it's basically an iptables rule without the possibility to give a description. 
Is there a way to create a separate zone or subzone for the admin host?

The advantage would be, that the configuration is more readable. 
I could create a ManagmentZone with special permissions. And when another `Admin-PC` comes to life, I can simply add its address to this zone.

Comment: You could just add these IP addresses to the `trusted` zone, or a new zone.

Comment: Thanks! I did not understand that I can add ip ranges to zones:


firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.2.0/24

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to create a separate zone?

Yes, you can create new zones:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#How_to_configure_or_add_zones.3F

> How to configure or add zones?
>
> To configure or add zones you can either use one of the firewalld
>   interfaces to handle and change the configuration. These are the
>   graphical configuration tool firewall-config, the command line tool
>   firewall-cmd or the D-BUS interface. Or you can create or copy a zone
>   file in one of the configuration directories.
>   @PREFIX@/lib/firewalld/zones is used for default and fallback
>   configurations and /etc/firewalld/zones is used for user created and
>   customized configuration files.

From http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-firewalld/

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=test
success
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```